# angular botón que al pulsar pasa un parámetro a una función para un filtro

Tags: php, angular, ionic

me estoy liando estoy haciendo un boton para que al apretar me selecione unos productos según unas categorías de una base de datos , el problema es que me han creado esta app y les dije que me comentaran el código para yo poder ir aprendiendo y toqueteando pero estoy más perdida que no se que.bueno tengo unos filtros creados si apretas un boton se abre una pagina y puedes aplicar estos filtros pero el caso es que ahora quiero aplicar varios filtros de unas categorías sin tener que entrar en la página de filtros simplemente al apretar un botón pues que aparezcan los productos de una categoría en concreto.

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {


     dummy = Array(20);
     product_list=[];
     search="";
     dummy_product_list=[];
  advancecat={
    'filter_category':'',
  };
  
  filterdata={
    'filter_category':'',
    'filter_minprice':'',
    'filter_maxprice':'',
    'filter_location':''
  };
```

he creado advancecat sin tener mucha idea copiando lo de abajo la verdad.y lo he agregado aquí el primer if

```
 show_filteresult(){
     var tmp_list=this.product_list;
     var self=this;

     if (this.advancecat.filter_category!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.category_title.toLowerCase().includes(self.advancecat.filter_category.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }
     

     if (this.filterdata.filter_category!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.category_title.toLowerCase().includes(self.filterdata.filter_category.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }

     if (this.filterdata.filter_location!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.address.city.toLowerCase().includes(self.filterdata.filter_location.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }

     if (this.filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || this.filterdata.filter_maxprice!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.price>=this.filterdata.filter_minprice && this.filterdata.filter_maxprice>=item.price ;
      });  
     }

     this.product_list=tmp_list;
```

en el html he creado un botón para llamar esa funcion.

```
<ion-button   (click)="show_filteresult()" style=" width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-left: 5px;" > 
  categoria plantas
    </ion-button>
```

pero no se como pasarle el parametro para que filter_category sea plantas si pongo plantas directamente entre las comillas me hace la búsqueda al cargar la pagina pero el boton o hace nada supongo que es evidente falta pasar el parámetro que no se como, lo he echo asi porque quiero poner mas de un botón con diferentes parámetros .

```
advancecat={
        'filter_category':'',
      };
```

si alguien pude decirme como pasar ese parámetro al apretar le doy las gracias.

Comment: Hola andrea te refieres a poner :   <ion-button   [(ngModel)]= "advancecat "(click)="show_filteresult()" style=" width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-left: 5px;" > 
  categoría plantas
    </ion-button>.    algo asi pero el valor plantas como se lo pasaría.

Comment: Lo que deseas es escribir el parámetro en una caja de texto y enviarlo?

Comment: hola no quiero que sea un botón con el parámetro ya definido , bueno varios botones con cada botón un parámetro

Comment: solo que estaba probando primero con uno para ver si me funcionaba.

Comment: Por cada categoría vas a crear un botón con el  parámetro definido?

Comment: si esa es la idea que cada botón filtre una categoría concreta

Comment: No creo sea buena idea y si la base de datos cambia y tienes 50 categorías lo cual sería 50 botones :) a menos que sean pocas categorías y no cambien jeje

Comment: bueno ya tengo un filtro , este solo será para unas cuantas categorías en concretas

Comment: sabes como puedo pasar ese parámetro al apretar el botón te lo agradeceria.

Comment: si ahorita estaba por publicar una respuesta jeje

Comment: ondia muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que quieres hacer es esto:

```
<ion-button (click)="show_filteresult('parametroCategoria')">Enviar</ion-button>
```

Y en el .ts lo capturas:

```
show_filteresult(parametro:any) {
  //Aquí lo defines al objeto  
  this.advancecat.filter_category=parametro;
  console.log(this.advancecat);
}
```

Aquí te dejo una demo [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-6yiqoa)

Comment: @lara Me comentas si es lo que quieres quizá no comprendí bien :)

Comment: Andrea gracias voy a ver como lo puedo implementar, y te cuento si me aclaro .

Comment: andrea creo que no lo implemento bien me da error

Comment: @lara Edita la pregunta y añade  el error que te sale

Comment: bueno creo que lo que intento es más complejo de lo que pensaba puesto que hay mucho mas codigo y me da error tal y como lo he planteado colocare todo el código para ver si me puedes orientar

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la idea es crear varios botones para que la lista de productos salga con una serie de categorías especificas por ejemplo apreto un boton y sale los productos de la categoría plantas.

el html sería:

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">

  <div class="div_searchbar">
    <ion-searchbar animated="true" mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="search"    placeholder="Busca en Mascota " [debounce]="250" class="search_bar" (ionChange)="onSearchChange()"></ion-searchbar>    
    <ion-button  fill="clear"  (click)="open_filter()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" mode="md"  name="options-outline"  ></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  


  
  
    <ion-button (click)="show_filteresult('plantas')">Enviar</ion-button>
   

  </div>

  <div class="filter_div" *ngIf="advancecat.filter_category!='' ">
    <div class="filter_item"  *ngIf="advancecat.filter_category!=''" >
      <span class="filter_label"> Categoria:</span><span style="margin:auto">{{advancecat.filter_category }}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn" (click)="advancecat.filter_category='';refresh_filter()"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
    


  <div class="filter_div" *ngIf="filterdata.filter_category!='' || filterdata.filter_location!='' ||  filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || filterdata.filter_maxprice!='' ">
    <div class="filter_item"  *ngIf="filterdata.filter_category!=''" >
      <span class="filter_label"> Categoria:</span><span style="margin:auto">{{filterdata.filter_category }}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn" (click)="filterdata.filter_category='';refresh_filter()"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_item" *ngIf="filterdata.filter_location!=''" (click)="filterdata.filter_location='';refresh_filter()">
      <span class="filter_label"> Ubicacion:</span> <span style="margin:auto">{{ filterdata.filter_location}}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_item" *ngIf="filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || filterdata.filter_maxprice!=''" (click)="filterdata.filter_minprice='';filterdata.filter_maxprice='';refresh_filter();"> 
      <span class="filter_label"> Precio:</span> <span style="margin:auto">{{filterdata.filter_minprice +'€'+ '  ~  ' + filterdata.filter_maxprice +'€'}}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content">
  <div class="main_content_div"  *ngIf="dummy?.length>0">    
    <ion-row class="items-row">
      <ion-col size="6" class="product_col" *ngFor="let product_item of dummy;let i = index">
        <div class="product_item">
          <ion-skeleton-text animated style="   width: 90%;  margin: auto; height: 25vw; "></ion-skeleton-text>

          <div class="product_infodiv">
            <div class="product_rowdiv"  >
              <ion-skeleton-text animated style=" width: 90%;height: 10px;margin: auto;  "> </ion-skeleton-text>
            </div>
            <div class="product_rowdiv">
              <ion-skeleton-text animated style=" width: 90%; height: 10px;margin: auto;  "> </ion-skeleton-text>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </div>

  <div class="main_content_div" *ngIf="dummy?.length==0">    
    <p class="title_p"> Productos cerca de ti </p>
    <ion-row class="items-row">
      <ion-col size="6" class="product_col" *ngFor="let product_item of product_list;let i = index">
        <div class="product_item">
          <ion-img class="product_image" [src]="product_item.image_list[0].file_url" (click)="open_product(product_item)" ></ion-img>

          <div class="product_infodiv">
            <div class="product_rowdiv"  (click)="open_product(product_item)" >
               <p class="product_price"> {{product_item.price +'€' }} </p>
               <ion-icon src="assets/icon/pin.svg" class="pin_icon"></ion-icon>
               <p class="product_city"> {{product_item.address.city }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product_rowdiv">
              <p class="product_title" >  {{product_item.title }}</p>
              <ion-icon *ngIf="product_item.user_id!=api.userdata.user_id" slot="icon-only" src="assets/icon/chat_btn.svg" class="chat_icon" (click)="open_chat(product_item)"></ion-icon>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <!-- <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content
        loadingSpinner="bubbles"
        loadingText="Loading more data...">
      </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
     -->
  </div>

 
 <div class="main_content_div" *ngIf="dummy?.length==0 && product_list?.length==0">    
  <p class="hint_p"> ¡prueva otro nombre! </p>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

el ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Router ,NavigationExtras} from '@angular/router';
import { UtilService } from '../utils/util.service';
import {FilterPage} from '../modals/filter/filter.page';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { orderBy, uniqBy } from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './home.page.scss'
  ]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  
  dummy = Array(20);
  product_list=[];
  search="";
  dummy_product_list=[];
  
  
  filterdata={
    'filter_category':'',
    'filter_minprice':'',
    'filter_maxprice':'',
    'filter_location':''
  };

  current_index=0;
  segment_size=6;

  constructor(public api: ApiService ,   public router: Router,    public util: UtilService,    public modalController: ModalController ) { 


  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
 
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    
    this.get_all_product();
  }

  onSearchChange() {
    console.log(this.search);
    this.product_list = this.dummy_product_list.filter((item: any) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
    });  
  }



  get_all_product(){
    this.current_index=0;
    this.segment_size=6;
      var data = {
        'user_id': this.api.userdata.user_id,
        'api_token': this.api.userdata.api_token
      };
    this.dummy = Array(20);

    this.api.get_all_product(data).subscribe((res) => {
        this.dummy = [];
        if (res.status == '1') {
          var tmp_result = [];

          for (let i=0;i<res.data.length;i++){
            let distance = this.distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(this.api.userdata.lat, this.api.userdata.lng, res.data[i].lat, res.data[i].lng);
            console.log('distance', distance);
            res.data[i].distance=distance
            tmp_result.push(res.data[i]);       
            
          }
           
          tmp_result = orderBy(tmp_result, 'distance', 'asc');

          this.dummy_product_list=tmp_result; 
          this.product_list=tmp_result;
          console.log(this.dummy_product_list);
          this.refresh_filter();
        }else{
          this.dummy_product_list=[];
          this.product_list=[];
        }
    }, error => {
      
      this.dummy = [];
      this.util.errorToast("Error en el servidor.");
    });
  }

  loadData(event) {
    var self=this;
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   console.log('load more');
    //   self.current_index=self.current_index+self.segment_size;
    //    console.log(self.current_index);
    //   // console.log(this.dummy_message_list);

    //   var segment_array=self.dummy_product_list.slice(self.current_index,self.current_index+self.segment_size);
    //   // console.log(segment_array);

    //   self.product_list=self.product_list.concat(segment_array);
    //   // console.log(self.message_list);

    //   event.target.complete();

    //   // App logic to determine if all data is loaded
    //   // and disable the infinite scroll
    //   if (this.product_list.length >= this.dummy_product_list.length) {
    //     event.target.disabled = true;
    //   }
    // }, 500);
  }



  distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    console.log(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    const earthRadiusKm = 6371;

    const dLat = this.degreesToRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    const dLon = this.degreesToRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    lat1 = this.degreesToRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = this.degreesToRadians(lat2);

    const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return earthRadiusKm * c;
  }

  degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  open_product(item){
    const navData: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        product_details:JSON.stringify(item)
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['app/home/product_details'],navData);
  }

  open_chat(chat_item){ 

    var data = {
      'user_id': this.api.userdata.user_id,
      'api_token': this.api.userdata.api_token,
      'type':'product',
      'product_id':chat_item.product_id,
      'auction_id':0,
      'seller_user_id':chat_item.user_id,
      'bid_user_id':this.api.userdata.user_id
    };

    this.util.show();

    this.api.open_chatroom(data).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.util.hide();
      if (res.status == '1') {        
        const navData: NavigationExtras = {
          queryParams: {
            chat_item:JSON.stringify(res.data)
          }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['chat'],navData);
      }else{
        this.util.errorToast("Can't open chat.Try again!");        
      }
    }, error => {
      this.util.hide();
      this.util.errorToast("Error en el servidor.");
    });


   }


   async open_filter(){
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: FilterPage,    
      backdropDismiss: false,
      componentProps: {
        'filterdata': this.filterdata
      }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned) => {
      if (dataReturned && dataReturned.data) {
         this.filterdata = dataReturned.data;
         console.log(this.filterdata);
         this.show_filteresult();
      }else{
        console.log("No Filter");        
      }
    });
      await modal.present().then(() => {
    });
   }

   show_filteresult(){
     var tmp_list=this.product_list;
     var self=this;


     if (this.filterdata.filter_category!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.category_title.toLowerCase().includes(self.filterdata.filter_category.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }

     if (this.filterdata.filter_location!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.address.city.toLowerCase().includes(self.filterdata.filter_location.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }

     if (this.filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || this.filterdata.filter_maxprice!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.price>=this.filterdata.filter_minprice && this.filterdata.filter_maxprice>=item.price ;
      });  
     }

     this.product_list=tmp_list;

   }

   
  

      
   refresh_filter(){
     console.log(this.filterdata);
    this.onSearchChange();
    this.show_filteresult();
    
   }


}
```

Comment: Es complicado ayudarte si un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: te doy las gracias creo que el problema es que necesito que ese parametro me cambie el valor de esto  advancecat={
    'filter_category:'aqui el valor del parametro al apretar el boton',
  };

Comment: no cambia al hacer esto? this.advancecat.filter_category=parametro;

Comment: vale ahora lo he conseguido no se si es la forma correcta pero me funciona con un boton , lo difícil sera ahora con mas de uno claro repetir una función por boton seria mucho codigo ,  es como me has dicho andrea .

Answer (score 0):

así lo puse

```
   filteresult(parametro:any){
    var tmp_list=this.product_list;
    var self=this;


    if (this.advancecat.filter_category=parametro){
     tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((parametro: any) => {
       return parametro.category_title.toLowerCase().includes(self.advancecat.filter_category.toLowerCase()) ;
     });  
    }

    this.product_list=tmp_list;

  }
```